# Proving that the binary relation defined by $xRy$ if $x \pmod{p} \equiv y \pmod{p}$, with $p \geq 2$, is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $R$ be the binary relation on $\mathbb{N}$ defined by $xRy$ if $x \pmod{p} = y \pmod{p}$. Prove that, for $p \geq 2$, $R$ is a equivalence
>   relation. Specify the equivalence classes of $R$.

I'm trying to figure out how to prove this. I know for an equivalence relation you need to show that the relation is symmetric, reflexive and transitive, but can I just do simple operations to the equation to show it?

Comment: What is your definition of $x \bmod p$?

Comment: Did you mean defined on $\mathbb{Z} = \{\ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$?

Answer (score 1):

The proper notation is $x \equiv y \pmod p$

Then $x \equiv y \pmod p$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x-y=kp$ for some integer $k$:

1. reflexive: $x-x=0p$
2. symmetric: if $x-y=kp$ then $y-x=-kp$
3. transitive: if $x-y=kp$ and $y-z=hp$ then $x-z=(k+h)p$

Answer (score 0):

To expound on the second part of the OP's question, the equivalence classes set up by the equivalence relation of modulo p contain all integers that yield the same remainder when dividing by a prime $p$.  To see this, note that any number $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ can be represented 
$$y=px+r$$
where $p$ is the divisor, $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the quotient, and $0\le r <p$ is the remainder.  But subtracting $r$ from both sides gives
$$y-r=px$$
which by definition of $\pmod{p}$ tells us that 
$$y\equiv r\pmod{p}$$